# Is a CRC32 as resilient as two CRC16 initiated differently?

Tags: language-agnostic, crc

Given a to-be-checked string `s`, an indipendently verified "salt" `t`, an `append` operator `+` and the arbitrarily sized cyclic redundancy check functions `crc2X()` and `crcX()`, is it the case that `crcX(s)+crcX(t+s)` has the same data degradation detection capability of `crc2X(s)` for the string `s`?

Comment: Wait, did you mean `crc2X(t+s)`?

Comment: @MarkAdler No, I meant it as written in the question. Feel free to ask if you need more info.

Comment: I'm not understanding the question, so I deleted my answer. I don't even see how you would compare two different error detection capabilities over two different messages.

Comment: @MarkAdler I shall clarify that only `s` is the string to be checked. `t` serves to scramble up the internal state so that an error that `crcX(s)` did not detect will be detected by `crcX(t+s)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

`crcX(t+s)` can be calculated from `crcX(t)`, `crcX(s)`, and the length of `t`. Therefore you have added exactly zero error detection information about `s` by appending `crcX(t+s)`. All you have added is error detection information about `t`.

`crc2X(s)`, for a properly chosen CRC polynomial, will have better error detection capability than `crcX(s)`, simply because it has more bits.

Comment: I did not know about that property. Consequently salting clearly won't make a difference. Example, given a same-length collision `crc32("a1sellers") = crc32("advertees")` it follows that `crc32("ABCa1sellersDEF") = crc32("ABCadverteesDEF")` for all equally sized prepended and appended strings and, in fact, it holds on all checksumming algos i tried (crc32, crc16, adler32, fletcher16).